# Passing a variable from onclick event to a fucntion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Been scratching my head all night on this issue. Im still learning Jquery and just starting with ajax. I am trying to implement something similar to this https://codeontime.com/print/learn/rest/jquery/crud-create-read-update-delete.

I have a simple edit button in which i stored the ID in in a data-ID attribute. For example below is what my button would look like.

```
<button class='edit_button btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xs' type='button' value='Edit' data-ID='1'></button>
```

What im trying to accomplish is to pass the data-ID value into a variable and pass it into my function. Here the listener I put in place to capture the ID and its working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".edit_button").click(function() {
var Button_ID = $(this).attr("data-ID");
IncidentManager.showIncidentDetails();  
});
```

The problem I have is that I need to pass the button_ID variable onlick to my variable function and dosent seem to be working correctly. I feel like im missing something there.

Below is my full script:

```
var IncidentManager = {
    // Returns the url of the application server of a demo web app.
    basePath: function () { return '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc'; },

    // This function will loadup the data into the modal form,
    showIncidentDetails: function (Button_ID) {
        if (Button_ID == null) return;
        alert(Button_ID);
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_Tableau_de_bord('+ID+')',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, incident) {

                $('#Description').attr('value', incident.Description);
                $('#Incident').attr('value', incident.Incident);
                $('#état').attr('value', incident.ÉtatValue);
                $('#Priorité').attr('value', incident.PrioritéValue);
                $('#DateDeDébut').attr('value', incident.DateDeDébut);
                $('#DateDeFin').attr('value', incident.DateDeFin);

            });
            }
        });
    },  

};

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".edit_button").click(function() {
var Button_ID = $(this).attr("data-ID");
IncidentManager.showIncidentDetails();  
});

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So why are you not passing it? `IncidentManager.showIncidentDetails(Button_ID);`

Comment: I gave it a try but dosen't seem to be picking it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pass the variable to the function - programming doesn't work by just having variables named similarly, hence what you want is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit_button").click(function() {
        var Button_ID = $(this).attr("data-ID");
        IncidentManager.showIncidentDetails(Button_ID);  
    });
});
```

also this bit:

```
....
url: '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_Tableau_de_bord('+ID+')',
```

You probably meant

```
url: '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_Tableau_de_bord('+Button_ID+')',
```

as there is no `ID` variable in your code.

---

Incidentally, you can use the jQuery `.data` function instead of `.attr`:

```
var Button_ID = $(this).data("id");
```

However, note that `.data` will treat your data attribute as lowercase.

Comment: Thanks Jamiec, i fixed up my code with your suggestions. For some reason the alert I put in the function is still not firing off. Seems like the Button_ID is still not being passed. Would you know why that would be?

Comment: Yes, I do. In my infinite wisdom of telling you to use `.data` I forgot to mention this lower-cases the item. So you need `var Button_ID = $(this).data("id");`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/0fnx3kvh/

Comment: That worked :). Seems like I got another issue on my page. Seems like my functions are not firing off on document ready but if I paste the code in my console it works fine. Strange ...

Comment: Finally figured out the second issue, since my buttons were loaded dynamically the .click wasent firing off properly since the DOM wasent ready. I ended up using `$(document).on("click", ".edit_button", function() { ` instead of `$(".edit_button").click(function() {`